# ng-show tr element inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm still pretty new to angular and am having trouble laying out the logic for my problem

Basically, I am using ng-repeat to generate a table filled with rows, and upon clicking any given row, to have a hidden row appear beneath the clicked on, so that I can load it up with data

My code looks as follows

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody ng-repeat="order in resp.Orders" >
        <tr ng-click='selectOrder(order);'>
            <td>{{order.OrderId}}</td>
            <td>{{order.Client}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show('order.IsSelectedOrder')>
            <td>Selected Order</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As the code stands, the list generates with both rows visible at all times. **At this point, that is the main problem**

My selectOrder function looks as follows

```
    $scope.selectOrder = function (order) {
        order.IsCurrentOrder = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect and I think the property you set in the selectOrder function is incorect. It should be:

```
<tr ng-show="order.IsSelectedOrder">

$scope.selectOrder = function (order) {
    order.IsSelectedOrder = true;
}
```

[Docs for ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Thanks. I figured out and was going to edit my post, but you literally beat me to it by a few seconds